# Covering groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am studying the Steiner system $S(5,6,12)$ and the ternary extended Golay code $\mathscr{C}_{12}$. The automorphism group of the Steiner system is the Mathieu group on twelve elements $M_{12}$ whereas the automorphism group of the Golay code is $2.M_{12}$, a double cover of this group.

I don't understand the meaning of "double cover" and I could not find any helpful explanation. I can only guess that it is meant in the way that any automorphism of $S(5,6,12)$ is also an automorphism of $\mathscr{C}_{12}$ and the latter is also preserved under the central involution, which multiplies every coordinate by $-1$. Is that correct or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: $2.M_{12}$ is a group $G$ with centre $Z$ of order $2$ and $G/Z \cong M_{12}$. But $M_{12}$ is not a subgroup of $G$, it is a quotient group, so it is not true to say that every automorphism of $S(5,6,12)$ is also an automorphism of $\mathscr {C}_{12}$. But it is true that the central involution in $Z$ multiplies everything by $-1$.

Comment: Okay, but if I understand this correctly, then still any automorphism of $S(5,6,12)$ **yields** an automorphism of $\mathscr{C}_{12}$ since it can be interpreted as an coordinate permutation and any such permutation induces an automorphism of $\mathscr{C}_{12}$, right?

Comment: More precisely it yields two automorphisms of $\mathscr{C}_{12}$, one being minus the other.

Comment: @lattice: An easier example of a "double cover" is the [quaternion group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion_group) $Q_8$ with $8$ elements. It is a double cover of the elementary abelian group $V_4 = Z_2\times Z_2$ with $4$ elements. If $Q_8$ acts on something, then in general its quotient group $V_4 = Q_8/Z(Q_8)$ doesn't necessarily act on it, as $V_4$ is *not* a subgroup of $Q_8$.